# How to set alignment of sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

I attach my code and output view. Can anyone help me out how to set alignment for sidebar. Thanks in advance.

## sidebar.blade.php

```
<!-- Sidebar Widgets Column -->
        <div class="col-md-4 container">
          <!-- Search Widget -->
          <div class="card my-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Search</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Go!</button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Categories Widget -->
          <div class="card my-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Categories</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Laravel</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">PHP</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">HTML</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">CSS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Side Widget -->
          <div class="card my-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Stats</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
              You can put anything            
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

## Master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>myblog</title>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="/public/css/blog-post.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body style="background-color: #e9ecef;">

    @include('partials.nav')

    @include('partials.jumbotron')

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        @yield('content')

      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->

       @include('partials.sidebar')
      
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    @include('partials.footer')

  </body>

<style type="text/css">

  .pagination {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 23px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: red;
    padding-left: 500px;
 }
    
  </style>

</html>
```

## Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Your blade code is working in sidebar as it is in left side . 

https://plnkr.co/edit/JC9wuoSrF13MHYLPCFMu

I dont know what the problem is  , what my primary guess look like is your div is broken or not having correct ending so its alligning along with the paginator .  .

Answer (score 0):

Your `sidebar` is a sibling to the `<div class="row">`. It needs to be a child, instead.

Also, don't use the `container` class on your `col-md-4`

```
<div class="row">
    @include('partials.sidebar')

    @yield('content')
</div>
```

This will, of course, assume your `content` always has a `<div class="col-md-8">` on it to compliment the `<div class="col-md-4>"` on your sidebar.

Comment: No luck. I'm getting same view. sidebar is under content but not beside of content.

Comment: @steven What does your `content` look like? just the few first `<div>` elements will do

Comment: No, talking about the **HTML** @steven